# IE10 hides behind Swing Window

Tags: java, swing, internet-explorer-10

I have a Swing Application.I am trying to open browser and is successful in it.  But When the browser is IE10, browser opens up but goes behind the Swing Application Window.
It works well in all other browsers.

Can anyone throw some light in this?

```
desktop.browse(new URI(url));
```

Comment: Have you used [`setAlwayOnTop`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setAlwaysOnTop%28boolean%29) at all?

Comment: That seems like very odd (and undesirable) behavior.  Have you checked the ..whatever IE 10 uses as a bug DB?  An interesting experiment might be to try launching it using a `Process`.  If it works as desired for a `Process` but fails with `Desktop` suggests 'problem with Java'.  Failure both ways suggests 'problem with IE 10'.  @MadProgrammer  I didn't think of that!

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'm not sure it's really and issue, given the fact that other browsers work, but I've seen `alwaysOnTop` do some strange things from time to between repaints

Comment: setAlwaysOnTop is not used .

Comment: It works for all other browsers.WE use a link button on Swing Application to open a HTMLpage located in Apache

Comment: Tip:  Add @MadProgrammer (or whoever - the `@` is important) to *notify* them of a new comment.  Or not, as you wish, when I think about it.. ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Will it make any difference if the rendered html page contains <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9">

Comment: I don't know.  Give it (try removing that or adding the IE 10 equivalent - it's new to me) a try in a realPageName-TEST.html